# [sorting=none]{biblatex} dont work in my Texstudio

Tags: biblatex, texstudio, biber

I add [sorting=none] in biblatex but when I do pdf + biber + 2x pdflatex compilations, bibliography dont ordonate it ...

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,safeinputenc,
sorting=none
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{villiers__1891,
    timestamp = {2016-07-08T10:22:30Z},
    journaltitle = {C. R. Acad. Sci.},
    journalsubtitle = {112},
    author = {Villiers, A.},
    date = {1891},
    pages = {536--538}
}

@article{loftsson_cyclodextrins_2007,
    title = {Cyclodextrins and their pharmaceutical applications},
    volume = {329},
    issn = {0378-5173},
    doi = {10.1016/j.ijpharm.2006.10.044},
    timestamp = {2016-08-22T13:06:37Z},
    langid = {english},
    number = {1–2},
    journaltitle = {International Journal of Pharmaceutics},
    shortjournal = {International Journal of Pharmaceutics},
    author = {Loftsson, Thorsteinn and Duchêne, Dominique},
    date = {2007-02-01},
    pages = {1--11},
    keywords = {Complexation,Cyclodextrin,Drug delivery,Formulation,History,Regulatory,Toxicology}
}

@article{freudenberg_uber_1938,
    title = {Über die {{Schardinger}} - {{Dextrine}} aus {{Stärke}}},
    volume = {71},
    issn = {1099-0682},
    doi = {10.1002/cber.19380710809},
    timestamp = {2016-07-08T14:23:45Z},
    number = {8},
    journaltitle = {Berichte der deutschen chemischen Gesellschaft (A and B Series)},
    shortjournal = {Ber. dtsch. Chem. Ges. A/B},
    author = {Freudenberg, Karl and Meyer-Delius, Margot},
    date = {1938-08-03},
    pages = {1596--1600}
}

@article{__????,
    timestamp = {2016-07-08T16:02:51Z},
    journaltitle = {Zentralbl. Bakteriol. Parasintenkd},
    journalsubtitle = {14},
    author = {Schardinger, F.},
    date = {1905},
    pages = {772--781}
}

@article{__????-2,
    timestamp = {2016-07-08T20:04:19Z},
    journaltitle = {Chemistry of the Saccharides},
    author = {Pringsheim, H.},
    date = {1992},
    pages = {280}
}  
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \autocite{villiers__1891}
        \item \autocite{__????}
        \item \autocite{__????-2}
        \item \autocite{freudenberg_uber_1938}
        \item \autocite{loftsson_cyclodextrins_2007}
        \item \autocite{freudenberg_uber_1938}
    \end{itemize}

            \printbibliography

              \end{document}
```

Biber compilation : Showing nyt

```
Processus en cours : "C:/texlive/2016/bin/win32/biber.exe" "document"

    INFO - This is Biber 2.5
    INFO - Logfile is 'document.blg'
    INFO - Reading 'document.bcf'
    INFO - Found 5 citekeys in bib section 0
    INFO - Processing section 0
    INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'document.bib' for section 0
    INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
    INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'document.bib'
    INFO - Overriding locale 'fr-FR' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
    INFO - Overriding locale 'fr-FR' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
    **INFO - Sorting list 'nty/global/' of type 'entry' with scheme 'nty' and locale 'fr-FR'**
    INFO - Writing 'document.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
    INFO - Output to document.bbl

    Processus terminé normalement
```

I have an another computer when its working, but I would like to know why on mine isn't working ... I have the 2 configuration files.ini if you wan compare ...

blg file :

```
[0] Config.pm:343> INFO - This is Biber 2.5
[1] Config.pm:346> INFO - Logfile is 'HADDOCK.blg'
[102] biber-MSWIN32:290> INFO - === 
[242] Biber.pm:351> INFO - Reading 'HADDOCK.bcf'
[523] Biber.pm:776> INFO - Found 7 citekeys in bib section 0
[578] Biber.pm:3493> INFO - Processing section 0
[651] Biber.pm:3657> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'HADDOCK.bib' for section 0
[660] bibtex.pm:1187> INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
[663] bibtex.pm:1048> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'HADDOCK.bib'
[902] UCollate.pm:66> INFO - Overriding locale 'fr-FR' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
[902] UCollate.pm:66> INFO - Overriding locale 'fr-FR' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
[903] Biber.pm:3306> INFO - Sorting list 'nty/global/' of type 'entry' with scheme 'nty' and locale 'fr-FR'
[934] bbl.pm:526> INFO - Writing 'HADDOCK.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
[940] bbl.pm:619> INFO - Output to HADDOCK.bbl
```

Comment: In fact, even time when I add [sorting=X] my biber compilation say " sorting list 'nty/global/'

Comment: The messages from biber says "found 7 citekeys", but your example uses only 5 citekeys. Also it writes with encoding "UTF-8" while your example uses safeinputenc. Did you really compile your example?

Comment: Yes It's this file ( I have delete references for the MWE ) I ask the same question in an another forum (texnique.fr) and this exmple work on another computers like it's write here... but just not on mine. Without safeinputenc it's the same...

Comment: Imho you didn't understand my remark: Your biber messages don't fit to the document. Rename your document.tex e.g. to `document-xyz.tex` and then recompile so that you can be sure that you are compiling the right file.  If the problem persist run `biber -trace document-xyz` and put the resulting `document-xyz.blg` and the log-file somewhere on the net for inspection. BTW: You should add a link to this question on the other question. It is only fair to tell people that the problem is discussed somewhere else too.

Comment: Regarding previous comments, I suggest you to check if `TeXstudio` considers another document as root (in `Options/Root Document`).

Comment: http://texnique.fr/osqa/questions/2301/sortingnone-ne-fonctionne-pas-sur-texstudio

Comment: blg file added on the quote

Comment: I have just this file on my computer, it's the good file ...

Comment: It works for me. Maybe you need to delete the `.bcf` and `.aux` files before you recompile. Then check the `.aux` file, it should show `\abx@aux@refcontext`, what does it say there? There are also some `abx@aux@defaultrefcontext`s what do they say? What sorting scheme do you find if you search for `sortlist` and `sortscheme` in the `.bcf`?

Comment: Yes I know unfortunatly... It works for each people but not just for me. Even if I delete all files ... and in the aux and bcf files, it's always write :\abx@aux@sortscheme{nty}
\abx@aux@refcontext{nty/global/}

Comment: Even argument that I write on [sorting=], biber compilation say *INFO - Sorting list 'nty/global/' of type 'entry' with scheme 'nty' and locale 'fr-FR'**

Comment: Did you delete all temporary files?

Comment: i compile with commands lines or with deleting all temporary files but nothing change... each time, biber compilation "don't read" the sorting and give my the bibliography like nty

Answer (score 1):

I have delete my texlives 2015 and 2016, delete my texstudio and after I install a new, texlive 2016 only and texstudio again, and this command works I try to compare files before and after to see if I found the problem